# Sort by date string (ascending) on Mongo

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a database with a date column in the format dd/mm/yyyy and I'd like to sort by the date in ascending order.

```
$cursor = $collection->find($filter)->sort(array('date' => 1, 'tripID' => 1));
```

The date is a string and I'm also filtering on the tripID but that aspect is working. The problem is that at present I'm getting:

```
01/01/2014
01/02/2014
02/01/2014
02/02/2014
```

What I would like is:

```
01/01/2014
02/01/2014
01/02/2014
02/02/2014
```

Is it possible to achieve this using the query or would it need to be done in the application?

Comment: You should convert your strings to dates in MongoDB, it's what you would have to do in the application anyway. The big problem is the strings here are not in lexicial order.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have the list given in your question

```
> db.dates.insertMany([{ "date": "01/01/2014" },
    { "date": "01/02/2014" },
    { "date": "02/01/2014" },
    { "date": "02/02/2014" }])
{
        "acknowledged" : true,
        "insertedIds" : [
                ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c4"),
                ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c5"),
                ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c6"),
                ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c7")
        ]
}
```

Within MongoDB 3.6 we can use aggregation framework and use the `$dateFromString` (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) pipeline operator to convert the string date in to a date and then sort the value:

```
> db.dates.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { "date" : { "$dateFromString" : { "dateString" : "$date"} } } },
    { "$sort" : { "date" : 1 } }
    ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c4"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c5"), "date" : ISODate("2014-01-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c6"), "date" : ISODate("2014-02-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c7"), "date" : ISODate("2014-02-02T00:00:00Z") }
```

Pior to MongoDB 3.6 there is a workaround to convert your string to a lexicial string date:

```
> db.dates.aggregate([
    { "$project" : {
        "date" : {
            "$let" : {
                "vars" : { "parts":{ "$split" : [ "$date", "/" ] } },
                "in" : {
                    "$concat" : [
                        { "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$parts" , 2 ] },
                        "-",
                        { "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$parts", 1 ] },
                        "-",
                        { "$arrayElemAt" : [ "$$parts", 0 ] } ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { "$sort" : { "date" : 1 } }
])

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c4"), "date" : "2014-01-01" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c6"), "date" : "2014-01-02" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c5"), "date" : "2014-02-01" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a314eae330cc13d0c9b10c7"), "date" : "2014-02-02" }
```

I know this is in javascript and you mentioned it was in php, but it's pratically the same, checkout the php documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php)