# Filtering arrays in a document or sub document in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, mongodb, bson, mongo-java-driver

My Java Code:

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbs.get(0)).getCollection(dbc.get(2));
    Bson Myfilter=Filters.and(Filters.eq("id", "144-12"), Filters.gte("lastTimestamp",StartPeriod ),
                Filters.lte("lastTimestamp", FinishTime));
    FindIterable<Document>  doc=coll.find(Myfilter).limit(5);
    for (Document Document : doc) {
        System.out.println(Document);
    }
```

for more help the corresponding Mongo Compass screenshot to  show the data structure:

[image]

and another screenshot from Mongo Compass and i have copied the JSON Document inside the red rectangle:

[image]

```
{"_id":"5db06ab680bd68ca32a84c6e","disconnected":false,"id":"144-12","lastTimestamp":"1571842738588","manufacturer":"gmb","modelName":"GMB_Mod1","signals":[{"event":"changed","signal":"InjectionUnitCycleParametersType.DosingTime","stability":"unstable","timestamp":"1571842736566","type":"INTEGER","value":"0","writable":"read","written":false},{"event":"changed","signal":"InterfaceType.Jobs.ActiveJobValues.LastCycleTime","stability":"unstable","timestamp":"1571842736584","type":"INTEGER","value":"0","writable":"read","written":false}],"tC":10}
```

I want to try to combine the filters with array fields and scalar fields. for instance int the photo I would like to combine filters based on "manufacturer" field and "written" field of the array

Comment: Please post a sample input document in _text_ (not image) format - the document you want to discuss.

Comment: Ok , i edit the post.

Comment: That is not useful @Moslem. You have to post a JSON format of the input document.  Try using _Mongo Shell_  or a GUI tool like _Compass_ and copy a document and post it here.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is to check for a field `signals` is an *array* and is *not empty*. Then, print a field (`value`) value from the array sub-document element, for all array elements.

The following is an example of how it can be achieved. I am using sample documents and print the `fldA` values. The following Java code has the array checks:

```
{ _id: 1, arr: [ { fldA: 11, fldB: "str123"}, { fldA: 29, fldB: "strxyz"} ] },
{ _id: 2, arr: [ ] }
```

*The Java Code:*

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://localhost/");
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
MongoCollection<Document>collection = database.getCollection("arrays");

Bson filterType = type("arr", "array");
Bson filterXpr = expr(Document.parse("{ $gt: [ { $size: '$arr' }, 0 ] }"));
List<Document> list = new ArrayList<>();

collection.find(and(filterType, filterXpr))
               .limit(2)
               .iterator()
               .forEachRemaining(list::add);

for ( Document doc: list) {
    List<Document> arr = (List<Document>) doc.get("arr");
    arr.forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.get("fldA")));
}
```

*The output:*

```
11
29
```

**NOTES:**

You can combine the filters I had defined (to check if the field is an array and the array has elements) with the filters `MyFilter` from your code using `Filters.and`.

```
// MongoDB Java driver imports
import org.bson.Document;
import org.bson.conversions.Bson;
import com.mongodb.client.*;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.*;
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you. I just want to go a bit deeper into my data in MongoDB. as you can see in the MongoCompass Photo, Signals array has a lot of fields for example "written","type","stability".  also even before the array "signals" we have some fields for example "id","manufacturer". what if i want to have some filter based on the array field? for example, a filter based on "stability", and what if i want to have at the same time a filter based on "manufacturer" ?  
and then based on these filters i want to take the value of the "value field" is it possible ?

Comment: To filter an array (like `signals`) based on a field like `type` you have to use an aggregation query. Here is an example: [aggregation using $filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html#example). The way to combine filters with array fields and scalar fields (like `id`) an aggregation query is the way to go. Field like `id` and `manufacturer` can be filtered in the `$match` stage of an [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation/).

Comment: Here is one I had answered few days back: [Mongo - Java - get all documents sort string date as date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427200/mongo-java-get-all-documents-sort-string-date-as-date/59463446#59463446).